# warning: passing argument 1 of 'quicksort' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, function, methods

I am receiving a warning: `warning: passing argument 1 of 'quicksort' makes pointer from integer without a cast`.

The function is declared as follows: `void quicksort(int x[], int first, int last)`

and i am calling the function using   `quicksort(values[noOfNums],0,(noOfNums - 1));`

Not sure exactly whats wrong here

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the (possibly invalid) value past the end of the array in as the first argument, rather than passing in the array itself (as a pointer).

The function call should probably look more like:

```
quicksort(values, 0, noOfNums - 1);
```